# Traveling from Toronto to Washington DC and New Jersey - is quarantine required?

Tags: usa, canada, covid-19, washington-dc

I want to travel to Washington DC from Toronto next week for non-essential purposes. I am a Canadian Permanent Resident and have a US B-2 visa. While I checked with United and they said I am allowed to enter the US, I don't find any quarantine requirements for Washington DC except for travelers entering DC from one of the US states. Also it does not state anything specific for travelers with less than 14 day stay in the US.

I want to take advantage of the $20 Acela tickets by Amtrak. For this, my plan is to enter Washington DC, stay in a hotel, take Acela the next day to NJ, take another Acela back to DC the same day, fly back to Toronto the next day.

Has anyone who recently travelled to Washington DC share their experiences?

Comment: NJ dies have quarantine requirements which may apply. What is the purpose of that journey?

Comment: Just a vacation. Desperately need a break.

Comment: You are running risks of infection and more spreading of the COVID 19 virus. Please find a break in your home area. We all feels the need to get away but please think about the people around you who may get infected because you want to travel 'just for fun'.

Comment: I assume you realize you will have to quarantine when you return to Toronto?

Comment: @DJClayworth Yes and I can do that from my home.

Comment: I don't even understand why you would do this. You're risking being responsible for spreading the virus to spend a few hours in New Jersey?

Comment: @ZachLipton:  My thoughts exactly.  Why not just avoid the quarantine by visiting the steel mills of Hamilton instead?  :::ducks:::

Comment: "I don't find any quarantine requirements for Washington DC except for travelers entering DC from one of the US states" There are no airports inside DC. Dulles airport is in Virginia. So if you enter DC, you will be entering from one of the states.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer will need to be broken down into four parts as you'll be dealing with multiple jurisdictions on this trip.

#### Entering the US

Currently the US does not place [any restrictions](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/153131/what-are-the-current-travel-restrictions-on-individuals-entering-the-united-stat?noredirect=1&lq=1) on passengers entering the US **by air**, only the land borders with Canada are closed. Hence immigration should allow you to enter with a valid US visa.

#### Entering DC

The local government [asks tourists](https://washington.org/dc-information/coronavirus-travel-update-washington-dc) to get tested 72 hours or sooner before traveling and to get another test on arrival if you're staying for more than 3 days. So if you can get a test in Toronto before traveling, you're good to go.

#### Entering New Jersey

The state [doesn't seem to require quarantine](https://covid19.nj.gov/faqs/nj-information/travel-and-transportation/which-states-are-on-the-travel-advisory-list-are-there-travel-restrictions-to-or-from-new-jersey) for international travelers ([unlike New York](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/158496/are-travelers-from-outside-the-us-obligated-to-follow-the-14-day-quarantine-in-n/159761#159761)) and the District of Columbia is one the list of territories exempted from travel restrictions. So you should be able to enter without being required to undergo a 14-day quarantine.

#### Coming back to Canada

Anyone coming to Canada (except for truck drivers and essential workers) is currently required to undergo a 14-day quarantine at home, so you should plan to spend 14 days in isolation when you return.

---

Overall I can recommend either staying in Toronto or amending your plans to visit a state [without travel restrictions](https://www.nytimes.com/2020/07/10/travel/state-travel-restrictions.html), such as Florida, Texas or Arizona. Remember to wear a high-quality mask (KN-95 or N-95) everywhere and avoid maskless indoor settings such as restaurants and bars.

Answer (score -1):

> Also it does not state anything specific for travelers with less than 14 day stay in the US.

The quarantine (which I don't think apply to you) doesn't prevent you from going to the airport.

---

Update: no idea why this answer got downvoted. [JonathanReez](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/9009/jonathanreez)'s answer points to https://washington.org/dc-information/coronavirus-travel-update-washington-dc, which confirms my answer: can go to the airport (and no quarantine). Also, no need for COVID test if staying less than 24 hours in DC.